# Is it possible to disable the enlargements and lightbox for mobile widths and make it work on resize?

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I am using  [slick lightbox](https://mreq.github.io/slick-lightbox/demo/) and it works great. Does anyone know how to disable the enlargements and lightbox for mobile widths? It seems that if the photos are already at their max size and they don't need an enlargement when viewing on phones. This is what I tried and it works, but it doesn't work on resize. Does anyone know how to make this work on resize?

```
    jQuery(function($){
    // This will fire when document is ready:
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // This will fire each time the window is resized:
        if($(window).width() > 1024) {
            // if larger or equal
             $('.slickLightPop').slickLightbox({
          lazy: true
        });
          
        } else {
          $('.galleryItem a').click(function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}); 
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the best solution.
I took the resize and media query out of the jQuery and just used the standard:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.slickLightPop').slickLightbox({
        lazy: true
    });
});
```

I then used CSS to disable the link for the image enlargement on the link class in a mobile width, max size media query:

```
.galleryItem a { pointer-events: none; cursor: default;}
```